# I accidentally hit ctrl C in git bash, Lvl 1 gitbash learning

Tags: git-bash, new-operator

Ok.
Lvl 1 gitbash, github learning practice.
After creating my repository, I was coping the remote adress from github, and pasting it to gitbash, my fast fingers did crtl C enter in gitbash and ^C  showed up!
What did I do and do I need to undo it before continuing my training exercise!?

Then I successfully copied and pasted adress to gitbash, but did not hit enter, because at the beginning of the line it added the following
^[[200~ then my adress

Comment: Don't panic. Ctrl-C in a terminal emulator "aborts". Type the command again and it will be fine. If in doubt, type `clear` and press enter.

Comment: You did nothing other than "aborting" the command you were typing (but not yet executed). If it added `^[[200~` then you're pasting something you shouldn't, the best advice for you to feel safe is to manually type the URL instead of pasting. What Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste, and this letter combination adds those characters in both ubuntu and gitbash, from ubuntu you should press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and from gitbash I am not sure. If in a terminal you have pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and you get `^C`, do not worry give enter that nothing will happen or just delete it and write the line you wanted to write. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> will only cause problems while you are doing some git operation, with that keystroke you will cancel it and you will have to run again that operation.

Answer (score 0):

The "^[[200~" that showed up is most likely there to distinguish copied/pasted text from typed text - according to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1532688/pasting-required-text-into-terminal-emulator-results-in-200required-text) post.

Ctrl+C on it's own will send the SIGINT signal and exit the current command/process - useful for infinite loops.  [This](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/c/ctrlc.htm#command) page has some more useful info.

There is nothing you need to worry about undoing.  You can check the gitbash documentation for how to paste copied text, but usually you can do so with a right-click or Ctrl+Shift+V.